# How to track a marker location is within a polygon area on drag-drop event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, point-in-polygon

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map,
  draggable: true
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) { 
  var result = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, polygonCoords);
  console.log(result);
});
```

location is the marker location and polygonCoords is the coordinates of the polygon(Both are defined previously). I am dragging the marker and after drag ends, I am listening the 'dragend' event and using the Google maps geometry library to check that the new location of the marker is within the polygon area or not.
But I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

[Click Here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y1hF.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be related  to the fact polygonCoords in not visibile inside event.addlistener

you could try using a clouser .. envrapping you listener inside  function with the proper value

```
var function myFunction( marker, myPolyCoords ) {

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) { 
    var result = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, myPolyCoords);
    console.log(result);
  });

}


myFunction( myMarker, polygonCoords );
```

Comment: I have solved the problem. I was passing the 'myPolyCoords' as an array of objects but actually we need to pass the polygon object itself.